# Minimising $\sum \frac{(-1)^{a_n}}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, maxima-minima

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive integers. Then I want to find the minimum possible value of
$$\Bigg|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{a_n}}{n!}\Bigg|$$

I know that the maximum absolute value is $e$ given where all of $a_n$ are odd or even, but I am unsure how to approach minimising the summation.

Comment: A more interesting question is how to minimize $$\left|\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{a_k}}{k}\right|$$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel How did you derive?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel The sum of other terms is a harmonic series...

Comment: @Szeto Basically: the harmonic series is divergent. We can choose signs such that the series converges to 0.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I think you have to elaborate.

Comment: @Szeto It's goal-directed evolution. Start with +1. Add negative reciprocals until the partial sum is negative. Add positive reciprocals from there until the sum is positive again. Since any tail of the harmonic series is divergent, each movement up or down takes a finite number of fractions, and the start and end of each movement always brackets 0. Since the individual unit fractions are decreasing, such series converges to 0.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I am quite convinced, but would not believe unless you can come up with a rigorous proof :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can arrange for the first two terms to cancel out by making $a_0,a_1$ of opposite parities, say $a_0=1,a_1=2$ – their magnitudes are both 1. But the magnitude of the $n=2$ term is larger than the sum of magnitudes of all the other terms. It follows that the minimum magnitude $m$ of the whole sum is achieved by setting all terms after $n=2$ to be of opposite sign as that of the $n=2$ term (i.e. $a_2$ is of opposite parity to $a_3,a_4,\dots$), with
$$m=\frac12-\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n!}=3-e$$
A possible $(a_n)$ achieving this $m$ would be $1,2,3,4,6,8,10,12,\dots$